# Why is there no dashboard in the latest Sonarqube version?

Tags: sonarqube

In the old version, there was a dashboard for the whole project from different views, but in the latest version there isn't. Why was this dashboard removed?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that rather than making you figure out which measures are most important, and making you figure out how to display them, recent versions of SonarQube handle the hard work for you with a standard, non-customizable project homepage, and the new Projects space.